# How do I submit a Spark jar to a EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, apache-spark, bigdata, emr

I have used the online AWS console to launch my cluster along with Apache Spark. I have a fat jar based on my Spark app and I have uploaded it to a S3 Bucket.
When I try to send it as a `Step with a Custom Jar`, the process fails.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [EMR bootstrap to install Spark](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark), and submit the job as described in the documentation:
https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/examples/spark-submit-via-step.md

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, my aws-cli outputs there is no add-steps method. Should I use its ruby client?

Comment: The documentation uses default aws cli, which has that method: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/index.html
You can either use the alternative command that you have in your CLI if there is one, or update to the latest version of default CLI implementation.